# Check for value if it exists in given ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file as follows:

```
ratio,range
g:k:l,1-500
g:c:m,501-1000
g:k:l,1001-1500
```

I have to check that a particular value exists in which of the ranges and then for given Y check whether it exists in the ratio. I have implemented in this way-

```
import csv , json
import ast

x=1600
y='k'
csvFilePath = "prorate - Sheet1.csv"
arr = []
#read the csv and add the arr to a array

with open (csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    # print(csvReader)
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        arr.append(csvRow)
arr= json.dumps(arr)
arr = ast.literal_eval(arr)
# print(arr)

for lists in arr:
    if int(lists['range'].split('-')[0]) <= x <= int(lists['range'].split('-')[1]):
        if y in lists['ratio'].split(':'):
            print(" Found {0} in range {1} for y={2}".format(x,lists['range'], y))
        else:
            print(" Not found {0} and x={1}".format(y,x))
    else:
        print("Not found {0} in all the ranges with y={1}".format(x,y))
```

When the value is not in the given range then error thrown is multiple times when I only want it to be once.I tried using try,except and else but I am not able to get it through. Also is there any more efficient way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a boolean flag outside the loop, set it if the condition is met, and test it after the loop has completed.

```
import csv 

x = 1600
y = "k" 
csvFilePath = "prorate - Sheet1.csv"

# Set the flag    
foundx = False

with open(csvFilePath, newline="") as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in csvReader:

        if (
            int(csvRow["range"].split("-")[0])
            <= x
            <= int(csvRow["range"].split("-")[1])
        ):
            foundx = True
            if y in csvRow["ratio"].split(":"):
                print(" Found {0} in range {1} for y={2}".format(x, csvRow["range"], y)) 
            else:
                print(" Not found {0} and x={1}".format(y, x)) 

    # Test the flag.
    if not foundx:
        print("Not found {0} in all the ranges with y={1}".format(x, y))
```

In terms of efficiency, you don't need the `arr` list: `csvReader` is already iterable.  Iterating over `csvReader` should generate a list of dicts for each row in the file, there's no need for `json` for `ast.literal_eval`, unless your csv file is  corrupted somehow.

If you want to stop searching once `y` has been found, insert a `break` statement like this to exit the loop:

```
            if y in csvRow["ratio"].split(":"):
                print(" Found {0} in range {1} for y={2}".format(x, csvRow["range"], y)) 
                break
            else:
                print(" Not found {0} and x={1}".format(y, x))
```